# Bot Framework Composer having issues with QnA Maker endpointkey

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I am trying to use a QnA Maker knowledgebase with a bot. The official instruction says to open settings with advanced (JSON) view to add the knowledgebaseid, endpointkey, and hostname. However, when I try to do that, it keeps showing "Loading."
So, I added the necessary parameters in the settings/appsettings.json file. It works temporarily, but if I close the Composer, it erases the endpointkey parameter. So, everytime I close the composer, I need to add the endpointkey manually.
When I published the bot to Azure, I am getting an error

> The format of value ‘EndpointKey System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]’ is invalid.

I used the App Service Editor to look at the appsettings.json file, and it shows

> "endpointKey": {
> "message": "Waiting for QnA Maker"
> },

How can I make the endpointkey permanent? Also, if I edit the file in App Service Preview, how can I build the bot from there?